# Continue the program after the end of the animation android studio

Tags: android, animation

I made an animation (ObjectAnimator)for a text view it work correctly but i have a question.
I wanna know is there any method that i can use immediately after animation duration finished ?
(I mean a method like onFinish when we use CountDownTimer)
I want the rest of methods and codes I have in app run when animation finished.Is there a solution for that?

```
ObjectAnimator deltaXAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(winMassage,"scaleX",1f,1.5f);
    deltaXAnimation.setDuration(300);
    deltaXAnimation.start();

    ObjectAnimator deltaYAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(winMassage,"scaleY",1f,1.5f);
    deltaYAnimation.setDuration(300);
    deltaYAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI there are proper callback methods in which you get Animation Start and end Listeners

```
ObjectAnimator deltaXAnimation = 
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(winMassage,"scaleX",1f,1.5f);
deltaXAnimation.setDuration(300);
deltaXAnimation.start();
deltaXAnimation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code might be understand well, creating a listener for ObjectAnimator

```
ObjectAnimator deltaXAnimation = 
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(winMassage,"scaleX",1f,1.5f);
deltaXAnimation.setDuration(300);
deltaXAnimation.start();
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) {
        //
    }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {

    }
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) {
        
    }
});
```

We can go also to your `ObjectAnimator`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //stop animation after 5 seconds
            deltaXAnimation.cancel();
        }
    }, 5000); //5000 equals to 5seconds
}
```

Hope this might help you